# Summing minimums with floor function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that for any positive integers $x, m, n$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\min\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{i} \right\rfloor,m\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m\min\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{i}\right\rfloor,n\right)$$

Intuitively this kind of sounds like it would be correct, but I am not sure how to write the proof to put it into words. I was thinking of doing casework on when $\min(\lfloor \frac{x}{i}\rfloor,m)$ changes to $m$, but then I got stuck.

Comment: Use `$\sum$` for summation instead of the letter sigma, it formats better. `\left` and `\right` are also useful

Comment: Where did you see this - how do you know it’s true?

Comment: Maybe you can explain your intuition or work out a simple example so your question better meets the standards of this Stackexchange site (where just asking for an answer and showing no work or attempts is not always welcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a $yz$-plane (not reusing the letter $x$), consider the region

$$\begin{cases}
0 < y \le m\\
0 < z \le n\\
yz \le x\\
\end{cases}$$

and count the number of integer lattice points inside that region. Counting points along the $y$ or $z$ directions give the two sides of the equation:

- When adding the lattice points for each $y$, the region can also be written as:

  $$\begin{cases}
  0 < y \le m\\
  0 < z \le \min\left(\frac x y, n\right)\\
  \end{cases}$$

  So the sum is $\sum_{y = 1}^m \min\left(\left\lfloor\frac x y\right\rfloor, n\right)$.
- Similarly, when adding the lattice points for each $z$, the region can be written as:
  $$\begin{cases}
  0 < z \le n\\
  0 < y \le \min\left(\frac x z, m\right)\\
  \end{cases}$$

  So the sum is $\sum_{z = 1}^n \min\left(\left\lfloor\frac x z\right\rfloor, n\right)$.

The same sum represented in the two ways is equal.